# Godot 3: How to add images without creating scenes?

Tags: godot

To add images, as far as I know you create a sprite in godot, but I don't want to do that, I'd like to do it pro grammatically using arrays, the reason is I'm creating a card game and I don't want to add 52 scenes and then attach 52 sprites.

Isn't there  a smarter way to do it? I haven't found anything. What I'm doing now  is I have a card scene and then I inherit from it the other cards scenes and attach sprites to them and add them to a 2d array but I'd like another way of doing that

Comment: Why do you need to create a new `Scene` for each new `Sprite`? Also assuming you've checked Godot's API, have you tried creating the `Sprite` object yourself, inside the code?

Comment: @TomTsagk I'm not sure how to create sprite object by coding it, all tutorials i followed create scenes using the editor and inherit it, I'd like to do it using Gdscript, not sure how though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your cards in a folder and set them names which follow a logic, like: card_0, card_1, card_2, and so on. As you can see, you can use a loop from 0 to 52 and using the method

```
load(your-path + number)
```

you can retrieve all cards.

I think you mean by a scene that you create a scene which handle the logic for a card. If this is the case, you need to instantiate the scene and call a method you defined, in order to pass the path of your card and load it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I used the sprite sheet found at https://www.emanueleferonato.com/2017/03/04/html5-deck-of-cards-management/ .

You can create a single Card scene with a single sprite. The sprite is set up as animation (4 Vframes by 13 Hframes), even though the animation won't actually play continuously.

Instantiate 52 instances of the Card scene, setting each instance's frame in a loop:

```
var deck = []
var c = load("res://Card.tscn")
for i in range(52):
    var n = c.instance()
    n.position.x = i * 30
    n.position.y = 200
    n.get_node("Sprite").frame = i  # <==== this is the trick
    deck.append(n)
    add_child(n)
```

Result: https://www.wookilar.com/img/cardswave.gif

Comment: what if you dont want animation?

Comment: **Any individual card is _not_ animated**. I.e. the King of Hearts card remains the King of Hearts forever; it doesn't change its face to some other suit/rank. The wavy pattern in my result screenshot was just a way for me to test out the `func _process()` of Godot. I was just changing the position.y of each card every frame.